# Can you use javassist to grab all the classes in a project?

Tags: java, javassist

Is there a way to use javassist to find a list of existing java classes in the system search path? I know you can use ".getDefault()" to return the system's default search path, is there a way list the classes on this search path without knowing the class names.

Comment: All classes in the classpath, you mean? What is "without having to specify the class name beforehand"?

Comment: Normally to modify a class file with javassist, you state "pool.get("class_name");" which searches the same path that the underlying JVM (Java virtual machine) has by default for class_name.class bytecode. I'm asking if it is possible to grab all the classes without grabbing just the one class ("class_name.class" in this example)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this requirement?

Comment: @Panayotis I added an answer let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

If you attach an agent/transformer to your project you can easily log or somehow save all the classes that are loaded into your project

```
public class Agent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader classLoader, String s, 
                                     Class<?> aClass, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, 
                                     byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                 // here you will see all the classes that are loaded into your project
                 // So just log its full name
                 System.out.println(s);
            }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this method only logs classes that are already loaded somehow, not all existing classes. I believe the good-old "scan all jars" method is the only one available.

Comment: This method intercept all the classes that are going to be loaded into your JVM. I does not log all the classes meaning that if there are classes in your project that in your run (e.g. JUnit tests) is not loaded that will not appear on the log

Comment: Just after a quick google query I found this that is basically solving the problem asked here with the same method I proposed https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/